# How do you use a turbo frame to replace an object creation form with an object show partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

I have a model `subscription_tier` with `show` and `edit` actions with corresponding views. I've wrapped each of these with a turbo frame

`<%= turbo_frame_tag subscription_tier do %>`

When I edit an existing subscription tier and save it, the turbo frame refreshes and shows my saved tier, but I'm unable to replicate this for creating *new* tiers.

My new tier frame:

```
<turbo-frame id="new_tier">
      <%= link_to "Add Tier", new_create_subscription_tier_path(sub_type: "Free"), class: "btn btn-primary mb-3 fs-6"
      %>
 </turbo-frame>
```

and in `new.html.erb`

```
    <turbo-frame id="new_tier">
      <%= render partial: "create/subscription_tiers/edit", locals: {
        subscription_tier: @subscription_tier
      } %>
    </turbo-frame>
```

Clicking Add Tier button successfully renders the form and I can save the object, but on save the turbo frame is destroyed with the error `Response has no matching <turbo-frame id="new_tier"> element`

I know this is because my `show` partial is wrapped with the `<%= turbo_frame_tag subscription_tier do %>`, but I don't know how to reconcile this.

Comment: If this helped you could you mark the answer as accepted, help other people that run into this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add a data tag to your new link i.e.

```
<%= link_to "new subscription", subscription_path, data: { turbo_frame: dom_id(Subscription.new) } %>
```

On the same page as this link ^^^^ you need to add

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag Subscription.new %>
```

I believe this is what your trying to accomplish

There is a fantastic tutorial that goes over all this stuff that is free [here](https://www.hotrails.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the OP figured this out, but for anyone looking for a possible solution, you could always set the turbo frame ID manually, for example:

```
<!-- new.html.erb, edit.html.erb -->
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'subscription_tier_frame' do %>
  <%-- form for subscription tier -->
<% end %>
```

and

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'subscription_tier_frame' do %>
  <%-- rendered subscription tier -->
<% end %>
```

That'll keep things in the same turbo frame.